# MYSQL Command Line cannot enter

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line

I am trying to create a table in MYSQL command line, this has worked before for previous tables but is now not working [Heres whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu3g3.png)
I have tried restarting the command line, not fixed it, I also dont know what id google.
The arrows -> turn into '> and i cannot enter (complete) the table.

I tried restarting the command prompt but this hasnt fixed it, googled but not exactly sure what i should google.
I was expecting to have the table made and be able to enter the table correctly.

Comment: You have a `'` character in the `RoldIDs` column name. That's being treated as the start of a string, it's waiting for you to type the ending quote.

Comment: If a name contains special characters you have to surround it with backticks. But I strongly suggest that you avoid putting special characters in column names like this.

Comment: Notice that the prompt changed from `->` to `'>`. That means you're inside a string literal.

Comment: Thank you to all who replied, I see the mistake i made :)